# Editing someone else's "too broad" question?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, needs-more-focus

Let's say I come across a question that, as currently stated, is too broad. But let's also say that it looks like the original asker is driving at a more specific question that I happen to think is really interesting, so I write an answer anyway (one that clarifies why the original question is too broad and specifies the sub-component that I'm answering). If that question is then (completely reasonably) put on hold as too broad, would it be appropriate for me to edit it to make it no longer be too broad? Or do I need to wait for the original author to do so, to ensure that I don't alter their intent? What if they never come back?

In the [example I'm referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225478/what-are-the-common-admissible-heuristics/29227162#29227162), I think that the question has real potential, but is being held back by the author's lack of knowledge of the relevant terminology. But then again, I could be misinterpreting their intentions.